# How to update database value based on checkbox? Jquery/php/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox

Been trying for hours trying to figure this out but not getting anywhere.

I am using labels as a checkbox. On check a checkbox, I would like the value of the database to be updated to 1. If the user unchecks the checkbox, I would like the value in the database to be update to 0.

This is the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
          <title>Territory</title>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
          
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>


<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$sql = "SELECT id, address, suburb, lat, lng, date, time FROM addresses";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
     
     
echo '<table style="margin:0 auto; max-width:320px;">
<tr>

</tr>';



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    echo '<tr>

      <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$row["address"].' '. $row["suburb"].'</span> <button style="float:right;" type="button">Go</button><br><br>


    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="home['. $row["id"].']" value="1"/>
        <label class="label" for="home['. $row["id"].']" id="home['. $row["id"].']"></label>
     
     <span id="dropdown">
        <select class="dropdown1" name="nhd1" id="'. $row["id"].'" >
          <option></option>
          <option>Mon</option>
          <option>Tue</option>
          <option>Wed</option>
          <option>Thu</option>
          <option>Fri</option>
          <option>Sat</option>
          <option>Sun</option>
        </select>

        <select class="dropdown2" name="nht1" id="'. $row["id"].'" >
          <option></option>
          <option>8:00am</option>
          <option>8:30am</option>
          <option>9:00am</option>
          <option>9:30am</option>
          <option>10:00am</option>
          <option>10:30am</option>
          <option>11:00am</option>
          <option>11:30am</option>
          <option>12:00pm</option>
          <option>12:30pm</option>
          <option>1:00pm</option>
          <option>1:30pm</option>
          <option>2:00pm</option>
          <option>2:30pm</option>
          <option>3:00pm</option>
          <option>3:30pm</option>
          <option>4:00pm</option>
          <option>4:30pm</option>
          <option>5:00pm</option>
          <option>5:30pm</option>
          <option>6:00pm</option>
          <option>6:30pm</option>
          <option>7:00pm</option>
          <option>7:30pm</option>
        </select>

        <select class="dropdown1" name="nhd2" id="'. $row["id"].'" >
          <option></option>
          <option>Mon</option>
          <option>Tue</option>
          <option>Wed</option>
          <option>Thu</option>
          <option>Fri</option>
          <option>Sat</option>
          <option>Sun</option>
        </select>


        <select class="dropdown2" name="nht2" id="'. $row["id"].'" >
          <option></option>
          <option>8:00am</option>
          <option>8:30am</option>
          <option>9:00am</option>
          <option>9:30am</option>
          <option>10:00am</option>
          <option>10:30am</option>
          <option>11:00am</option>
          <option>11:30am</option>
          <option>12:00pm</option>
          <option>12:30pm</option>
          <option>1:00pm</option>
          <option>1:30pm</option>
          <option>2:00pm</option>
          <option>2:30pm</option>
          <option>3:00pm</option>
          <option>3:30pm</option>
          <option>4:00pm</option>
          <option>4:30pm</option>
          <option>5:00pm</option>
          <option>5:30pm</option>
          <option>6:00pm</option>
          <option>6:30pm</option>
          <option>7:00pm</option>
          <option>7:30pm</option>
        </select>
        </span>
</div>
        <input style="width:98.5%; margin-top:5px;" type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Add note">
        <br><br>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>


    </tr>';
echo '</div>';
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo '</table>';

$conn->close();

?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var home = 0;

       if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
            var home = 1;
       }

        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
             url:"updateaddress.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{home:home,id:id,},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
       });

   });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name=nhd1]').change(function(){
        var nhd1 = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:"updateaddress.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{nhd1:nhd1,id:id,},
          });
        });
      });


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name=nhd2]').change(function(){
        var nhd2 = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:"updateaddress.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{nhd2:nhd2,id:id,},
          });
        });
      });

//learn to refresh page just in case more than one group working on map

</script>
```

```
      echo '<tr>

      <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$row["address"].' '. $row["suburb"].'</span> <button style="float:right;" type="button">Go</button><br><br>


    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="home['. $row["id"].']" value="1"/>
        <label class="label" for="home['. $row["id"].']" id="home['. $row["id"].']"></label>

    </div>
        <input style="width:98.5%; margin-top:5px;" type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Add note">
        <br><br>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>


    </tr>';
echo '</div>';


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

       if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
           var home = 1;
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
             url:"updateaddress.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{home:home,id:id,},
       }

        });
   });
});

</script>
```

This is the query:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
$home = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['home']);
$nhd1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nhd1']);
$nht1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nht1']);
$nhd2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nhd2']);
$nht1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nht2']);

if(isset($_POST["home"])) {
  $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET home='$home' WHERE id=$id";
  if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){

    } else {
      echo "error" . $sql . "<br>".$conn->error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another input checkbox with same name and value of 0. If you don't click the checkbox, it will return the input box with same name and value of 0 or otherwise it will return value of 1.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="home['. $row["id"].']" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="home['. $row["id"].']" value="0"/>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried this but couldn't get it to work. I've actually hidden the checkbox and am using a label (or image) for the checkbox.

Comment: Have you added those two lines I have given? or just one?

Answer (score 0):

In the below code block, there was problem with your checkbox id not correctly set, as well as its value. I fixed it **with:**

```
echo '<tr>

      <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$row["address"].' '. $row["suburb"].'</span> <button style="float:right;" type="button">Go</button><br><br>


    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id" value="'.$row["id"].'"/>
        <label class="label" for="home['. $row["id"].']" id="home['. $row["id"].']"></label>

    </div>
        <input style="width:98.5%; margin-top:5px;" type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Add note">
        <br><br>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>


    </tr>';
echo '</div>';
```

You have syntax errors in your JQuery script. They're fixed. Also you're not setting home = 0 when uncheck happens. And you don't check for status response from server. I added that as well.

**Try this:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var home = 0;

       if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
            var home = 1;
       }

        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
             url:"updateaddress.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{home:home,id:id,},
             success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
       });

   });
});

</script>
```

In your updateaddress.php, I added an status output to notify you of successful update.

**Change to:**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

print_r( $_POST );

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
$home = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['home']);
$nhd1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nhd1']);
$nht1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nht1']);
$nhd2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nhd2']);
$nht1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nht2']);

if(isset($_POST["home"])) {
  $sql = "UPDATE addresses SET home='$home' WHERE id=$id";
  if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "Success";
    } else {
      echo "error" . $sql . "<br>".$conn->error;
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I've also tried this but couldn't get it to work. Could it be something to do with this line... <input type="checkbox" name="id id="id" value="'.$row["id"].'"/>  ?

Comment: Try <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id" value="'.$row["id"].'"/>

Comment: And make sure $row["id"] has value.

Comment: Sorry still can't get it to work. $row["id"] has value of id in database. When using this code <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id" value="'.$row["id"].'"/>, the label no longer toggles. I tried showing the actual checkbox and testing with that but still can't get the values to update in the database

Comment: Check the update to updateaddress.php. I added print_r( $_POST );
 at the top. Do test again so you know the data you're dealing with clearly.

Comment: Regarding the label not toggling. You can revert to the old checkbox code : <input type="checkbox" name="home['. $row["id"].']" id="home['. $row["id"].']" value="1"/>.  Changes will still work. I don't think that's the value you need though for you checkbox. Resume test, and tinker from there.

Comment: Can you post the code where you get your $row data?

Comment: Thanks but still no can't figure it out. Going to have to try tomorrow.

Comment: sorry just saw the extra comments. Just updated the code to show whole file. Thanks.